# Android SDK Build Tool - how to find which dependencies use it?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-build

**Context:**

I am moving our org's infrastructure to Graviton which has arm64 architecture. Our Android build requires multiple build-tool versions. The lowest best `build-tools;30.0.3`

**Problem:**

I cannot install `build-tools;30.0.3` on arm based machine so I am exploring hoping that I can remove/upgrade dependencies that depend on `build-tools;30.0.3`. I am relative new to Android and from my Google search it doesn't seem there is a straight forward way to find dependencies that uses a specific version of SDK....Any ideas what I can do here?

Comment: Related issue ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227219818

Comment: ```./gradlew app:dependencies``` should be helpful too. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html